# unable to get values in list view by using simple cursor adapter android?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

In my android app i want to display the list which is retrieving the values from DB .I m using simple cursor adapter to do so,but list view is empty.Here is my code.my list view have two rows. How can i use simple cursor adapter in app.what i m doing wrong.Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

```
    //list.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/android:list"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>


   // textview.xml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/column1" android:background="@drawable/mid"
        android:layout_height="30dp" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.03"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/column2" android:background="@drawable/mid"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>


    </LinearLayout>




    public class AddFood extends ListActivity{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.listxml);

          DataBaseHelper db = null;
        try {
            db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           SQLiteDatabase database=  db.getReadableDatabase();
          Cursor c=database.query("food_list", new String[]{"_id","food_items"}, null, null, null,null,null);
          startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] displayfield=new String[]{"_id","food_items"};
         int[] displayViews = new int[] {R.id.column1,R.id.column2}; 

       SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.textview, c,displayfield , displayViews);
          this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

          c.close();   

    }

    }
```

Comment: exactly same is happening with me.looks like we are on the same boat drowning apparently .

Comment: i even specified the list view id as->"@android:id/list". But nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

For list.xml use:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

In class file:

do not use c.close();

and use:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.textview, c,displayfield , displayViews);
          setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```